# Error:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, ms-office

I built my dll in a 64Bit machine with Office2010 64Bit, when i use that dll in a 32bit(xp/office2003) machine am getting this error.

> `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have reference of VBIDE in my project, Looks like based on the office version installed in the PC where Project is being built - the version of Vbe.Interop gets recorded in the dll. How can I avoid this - ie, environment neutral build..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Ruled out: ---You might have copied the required assemblies from somewhere. But the .NET assembly Microsoft.Vbe.Interop will require other (native) DLLs to be present. These are probably not present on your system.

I think you may need to install a version of Microsoft Office in order to fix this.----

**To trouble shoot what gets loaded**, and what the fusion loader looks for (native) DLLs, turn on fusion logging in the registry:

> Add the following values to
>
> ```
>  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
> ```
>
> Add:
>
> ```
>  DWORD ForceLog set value to 1
>  DWORD LogFailures set value to 1
>  DWORD LogResourceBinds set value to 1
>  String LogPath set value to folder for logs e.g. C:\FusionLog\
> ```
>
> This folder must exist, and end with the backslash

<sup>(instructions copied from [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net/1527249#1527249))</sup>

Comment: Microsoft office is available in both the systems(where i build and where I install my app). version 14.0.0 of VBIDE is from Office 2010 where as the PC where I install my build has office 2003 (ie, VBIDE version 12.0.0) - ill try fusion log too